# Making continuation monad wrapper instance of Monad class

Tags: class, haskell, instance, monads, continuations

I have type `Foo` which is simple wrapper around `Cont a a`. I would like to make `Foo` type an instance of `Monad` class. I try this:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

newtype Foo a = Foo {unFoo :: Cont a a}

instance Monad Foo where
    return = Foo . return
    Foo inner >>= func = Foo (inner >>= newFunc)
        where newFunc x = (unFoo $ func x)
```

But I got this error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for >>= :: Foo a -> (a -> Foo b) -> Foo b
      at Classes.hs:7:5
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for >>= :: Foo a -> (a -> Foo b) -> Foo b
      at Classes.hs:7:5
Expected type: ContT b Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a
  Actual type: Cont a a
In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `inner'
In the first argument of `Foo', namely `(inner >>= newFunc)'
In the expression: Foo (inner >>= newFunc)
```

How to add `Monad` instance for `Foo` correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make `Foo` into a `Monad`.

First, let's point out that `Foo a`  is an elaborate way of writing `(a -> a) -> a`.

```
runFoo :: Foo a -> ((a -> a) -> a)
runFoo = runCont . unFoo

foo :: ((a -> a) -> a) -> Foo a
foo = Foo . cont
```

There's only one way we can define `(>>=) :: Foo a -> (a -> Foo b) -> Foo b`. We need an `a` to pass to the arrow `a -> Foo b`. The only thing we have that has any `a`s is a `Foo a`, which is equivalent to `(a -> a) -> a`. It will give us an `a` if we can provide a function of type `a -> a`, which there's only one of, `id`. So our only choice for how to get an `a` is to pass `id`.

```
instance Monad Foo where
    return = Foo . return
    ma >>= f = f (runFoo ma id)
```

This will fail one of the `Monad` laws, `m >>= return ≡ m`. We will write a counter example that lives in `Foo`.

```
counterExample :: Foo Int
counterExample = foo (\f -> if f 0 == 1 then 7 else 13)
```

The counter example results in `13` when passed the identity function `id`,  but only `7` when passed the successor function `(+1)`.

```
print $ runFoo counterExample id
print $ runFoo counterExample (+1)

13
7
```

Due to the `Monad` laws, `counterExample' = counterExample >>= return` should be exactly the same as `counterExample`, but it can't be. `>>=` already passed `id` to the function and only `return`ed the result, `13`. `counterExample'` doesn't do the same thing as `counterExample`.

```
let counterExample' = counterExample >>= return
print $ runFoo counterExample' id
print $ runFoo counterExample' (+1)

13
14
```

Since there was only one possible implementation of `>>=` and it isn't correct there is no correct `Monad` instance for `Foo`.